# Hidden when first screen and show random image by click [Web Ar, Aframe, Ar.js ]

Tags: aframe, ar.js

i want to hidden this component, and it will be show when i click button take-phot,
because, it always show frame  defined by height and width> is blackbefore i click button take-phot

```
  <a-image src="#my-image"
                 position="-0.05 1.5 -7" height="2" width="2">
        </a-image>
        <a-entity animation="property: visible; to: true; startEvents: materialtextureloaded"
                  material="src: #my-image"
                  visible="true"></a-entity>

    </a-scene>
    <div class="ui">
        <a id="take-phot" title="Take Phot"><i class="material-icons">photo_camera</i></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var video = document.getElementById("vid");
    video.play();

 /*   var pln = document.querySelector("#my-image");
    pln.setAttribute('visible', true);*/

    var myPix = new Array("ass/5.png", "ass/10.png", "ass/20.png", "ass/30.png");
    var take_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#take-phot');

    take_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        choosePic();
    });
    function choosePic() {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
        document.getElementById("my-image").src = myPix[randomNum];
        take_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
    }
</script>
```